# Temporarily entering the debugger in IPython

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb

In IPython, with `%pdb` enabled, I can hit Ctrl-C and be dropped to a Python debugger console at the exact point I stopped the program.

However, at this point the program is entirely stopped, and I can't resume he execution even if I run `continue` in the debugger.

Is IPython able to do that, then let me resume the execution of the program when I'm done?

*Note: I know about `pdb.set_trace()`, but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to quickly, temporarily stop IPython for quick harmless checks instead of having to manually add `set_trace` in my code, if possible.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I can hit Ctrl-C and be dropped to a Python debugger console at the exact
point I stopped the program.
```

Ctrl-C is interrupting your program, which raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`, when you resume with `continue` you continue ...and interrupt your program as asked by the Ctrl-C you sent. Ctrl-C is not to "pause" the program in debug mode at one certain point.

What you are looking for is to set a breakpoint a one particular line, like `%run -d` allow you to do. See `%run?`.

Comment: I actually don't want to set a breakpoint, I'd like to "pause" the program whenever I want, during execution, to be able to inspect variables. For example, I would do that based on the log output if I saw a weird line and wanted to know more, but didn't want to stop the program right away. Is it possible?

Comment: Not easily, just a dumb if statement that execute a dumb line with the breakpoint if it sees something special. IMHO, Seeing how fast things are proceed, it would be hard to stop the program reliably at some point with a user signal.

Comment: If debugging performance problems, you might want to stop the program when the things are *not* proceeding fast in a particular routine.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of corner cases with this type of thing.  However adding a signal handler to your usercustomize.py gets you quite far:

```
cat >> $(python -m site --user-site)/usercustomize.py <<EOF
import signal, pdb
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda *args: pdb.set_trace())
EOF
```

Now when you launch python, you will get that signal handler installed.

For example, you can now interrupt the SimpleHTTPServer:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
^C--Return--
> [...].local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/usercustomize.py(3)<lambda>()>None
-> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda *args: pdb.set_trace())
(Pdb) locals()
{'__return__': None, 'args': (2, <frame object at 0x10245b238>), 'os': <module 'os' from '[...]/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>}
```